# Server 2012 won't lock

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 Standard machine at home that I connect to via Remote Desktop from work.  The problem is my RDP session stays active even if my local machine is locked.  I'd like my remote computer to lock after a couple minutes of inactivity.  I've tried setting the screensaver and changing power options but none of these have worked.  Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bridgetonova.com/2007/11/how-to-lock-computers-when-idle-by-using-gpo.html

The idea is that you are enabling the screensaver option, but instead of specifying a real screensaver, you just make Windows execute the following command:
%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

This only locks the workstation without actually launching a screensaver.

Check the link for more detailed info.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried creating a scheduled task based on idle time with the command you mentioned but I wasn't able to get it to work.  What I eventually did is install the Remote Desktop Services role then configure the following GPO policy: Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Remote Desktop Services>Remote Desktop Session Host>Session Time Limit>Set time limit for active but idle session.  I set it for 5 minutes and it disconnects my session which is good enough for me.  I got the info from this TechNet article: https://goo.gl/dgfWlM